# why __init__ is called before object created?

Tags: python, init

```
class Point(object): 

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        print 'point ({x},{y}) created.'.format( x=self.__x, y=self.__y )

class Line(object):

    def __init__(self, start_point=Point(), end_point=Point()):
        print 'Line.__init__ called.'
        self.start = start_point
        self.end = end_point

def test_line():
    p1 = Point(1,1)
    p2 = Point(2,2)
    line1 = Line(p1, p2)

if __name__=='__main__':
    test_line()
```

When I run this script, it gives the result:

```
point (0,0) created.
point (0,0) created.
point (1,1) created.
point (2,2) created.
Line.__init__ called.
```

I don't know why Point.__init() is called before line1 is created.

Comment: on a side note, you can create a `Point` class easily with `collections.namedtuple('Point', 'x y')` but I see this is just an example, only mentioning this for future visitors

Comment: @jamylak so I can't write this way: `line2 = Line((1,1), (2,2)) ` except I use your new method above ?

Comment: Sorry I missed some code: `Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', 'x y'); Point(1, 2) # example` you can also write it this way, subclassing a namedtuple: `class Point(collections.namedtuple('Point', 'x y')): ` also works. Search `collections.namedtuple` on google

Answer (score 5):

```
def __init__(self, start_point=Point(), end_point=Point())
```

Default function parameters are members of the function itself and are created when the function is defined, not at runtime. So each instance of `Line` uses the same `start` and `end`

The common way to work around this is set them by default to `None`:

```
def __init__(self, start_point=None, end_point=None):
    if start_point is None:
        self.start = Point()
    if end_point is None:
        self.end = Point()
```

Comment: You mean: when Line is declared, Point.__init__ is called?

Comment: @little白 Python doesn't have declarations, that's part of the definition so in a way yes

Comment: @chepner I realised that the shorter version could cause confusion so deleted it

Comment: you may missed something: `if start_point is not None: self.__start = start_point `

Comment: @little白 fixed that, I wouldn't use `__start` unless you need the [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node67.html)

Comment: The OP's code might be fine as is, as long as no one ever does anything like `aLine.start.x = 10`.